# add multiple lines at beginning of file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have many files within the same subdirectory that looks like:

```
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

i.e. two columns, where the first line always begins with the number 10.

I would simply like to add lines 1-9 to the beginning of each file i.e.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9 
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

I don't care about appending the second column.

I know I could do

```
sed -i '1i1' FILE
```

to add a first line, but do I have to type this command out for each additional line I want to add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
seq 1 9 | cat - file.in > file.out
```

Where `file.in` is the input file you mentioned, and `file.out` is the name of the desired output file.

Or, even shorter (thanks @william-pursell):

```
{ seq 1 9; cat file.in; } > file.out
```

Comment: You can just pipe `seq 1 9` directly, without the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, it seems like unnecessary extra io to pipe the data to cat: `{ seq 1 9; cat file.in; } > file.out` works fine (if you have seq; if not stick with the for loop.)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `cat <(seq 9) file.in` vs `{ seq 1 9; cat file.in; }`?

Answer (score 6):

If you have gnu awk then you can use `inplace` editing in awk and avoid hardcoding ending number by reading existing value from the 1st record:

```
awk -i inplace 'FNR==1{for (i=1; i<$1; i++) print i} 1' *.txt
```

Change `*.txt` to some other glob matching your files.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the shortest one liner you can use.

```
sed -i -e1i{1..9} *.txt
```

This is equivalent to

```
sed -i -e1i1 -e1i2 -e1i3 -e1i4 -e1i5 -e1i6 -e1i7 -e1i8 -e1i9 *.txt
```

It uses `bash`'s brace expansion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Unix / POSIX / Linux `cat` utility to **concatenate** and print files.

You can use `<(seq 5)` as a replacement for a file to create the beginning sequence. So you can do:

```
$ cat <(seq 5) file
1
2
3
4
5
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

Then if you want the effect of editing in place, you can do:

```
$ cat <(seq 5) file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Then:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

---

If you don't have `seq` you can do:

```
$ cat <(echo {1..5} | tr ' ' '\n') file
```

instead. (Using 5 lines vs 9 in your example. Obvious how to change that...)

If you have many files, or you want to actually create the second column, you may want to create a header string:

```
$ header=$(for ((x=1; x<=5; x++)); do printf "%s #\n" $x; done)
$ echo "$header"
1 #
2 #
3 #
4 #
5 #
```

Then you can use that string instead of running `seq` or something:

```
$ cat <(echo "$header") file
1 #
2 #
3 #
4 #
5 #
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert multiple lines with `sed` by putting backslash after the `i` command.

```
sed -i '1i\
1\
2\
3\
4\
5\
6\
7\
8\
9\
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e '1!b;'"$(printf 'i%d\n' {1..9})"
```

This is equivalent to running

```
sed -i -e '1!b;i1
i2
i3
i4
i5
i6
i7
i8
i9
'
```

but easier to write. The `1!b` skips the rest of the commands on lines other than the first, but you could also use a `1` address instead.

```
sed -i -e "$(printf '1i%d\n' {1..9})"
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you might like pure bash:

```
$ cat file4
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
$ printf '%s\n%s\n' {1..9} "$(<file4)"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10 A
11 T
12 A
13 C
15 A
```

To replace the original file contents you can do it like:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' {1..9} "$(<file4)" >file44 && mv -f file44 file4
```

Also `sed -i` this is what it does in the background (check sed manpages)

For multiple files you can use a loop:

```
for f in *;do printf '%s\n%s\n' {1..9} $(<"$f") >tmp"$f" && mv tmp"$f" "$f";done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1e seq 9' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

On the first line of each file evaluate the command `seq 9`.